# Cross origin issue when upload to aws

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-dropzone

Here is put request

```
axios({
  method: 'PUT',
  url: signedRequest,
  data: file, 
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
})    
.then((response) => {            
   console.log(response)
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error)
});
```

And here cors config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
   <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
   <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
   <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
   <MaxAgeSeconds>9000</MaxAgeSeconds>
   <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And here is cross origin error

```
Failed to load https://tochpro.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/wehab/373-285x215.jpg%20%20%20%20?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIH7OJGP3PNYIN5YQ&Content-Type=multipart%2Fform-data&Expires=1559998463&Signature=3iLYA0VwD3SjkHOkPfCQALvLSk0%3D: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Please help me to get out of this error... And please let me know what i am missing here...

Comment: You need to allow OPTIONS method.

Comment: Can you please show me how I can do?

Comment: Same way you did GET and PUT...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what's going wrong from that, nothing jumps out... though from my experiences the problem has been more about the signedurl matching up with what S3 receives.

Off the top of my head it could be one or more of the following:

- the content type should be that of the file being uploaded, e.g. image/jpeg
- additional params that are not allowed (ACL or CacheControl got me for a while)
- sometimes the browser gets in the way with local host, or browser security headers in your app

*Here is how my working solution is constructed...*

An extract from the lambda that constructs the url:

```
var bodyJson = JSON.parse(event.body);
var params = {
    Bucket: process.env.BUCKET,
    Key: 'path/to/file/' + bodyJson.filename,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: bodyJson.filetype
};
var s3 = new aws.S3();
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) { ... });
```

I am using the ng-file-upload in AngularJS, but I understand that it is a standard http request:

```
Upload.http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: signedUrl,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': fileToUpload.type
    },
    data: fileToUpload
}
```

S3 CORS Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Hope this helps you, or someone else in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... `Upload.http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: signedUrl,
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': fileToUpload.type
    },
    data: fileToUpload
}` I get response after put call but the data is blank string...